# ¿Cómo saber en que div está posicionado mi mouse si los dos tienen la misma clase?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Holaaaa, tengo un proyecto donde estoy ocupando una animación en JavaScript donde si pasas el mouse sobre un div, este se mueve en relación a la posición del mouse, y este efecto lo quiero aplicar a varios div con la misma clase, ¿como puedo hacerlo?

Ya intenté haciendo un contenedor padre donde están mis dos div y obteniéndolos como hijos, pero al tener la misma clase, cuando hago hover sobre un div se ve afectado el otro

Entonces necesito saber como darle "individualidad" a cada div a pesar de que tengan la misma clase, porque la animación que quiero implementar tiene que afectar a varios elementos a la vez

O pueden darme alguna recomendación o algún cambio

```js
//Movement
const card = document.querySelector(".card")
const main = document.querySelector(".main")

//Items
const sneaker = document.querySelector(".sneaker img")
const title = document.querySelector(".title")
const purchase = document.querySelector(".purchase")
const info = document.querySelector(".info")

//For
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.container')
let y = divs.length

//Movement Animation
for (let i = 0; i < y; i++) {
  divs[i].addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    let xAxis = (window.innerWidth / 4 - e.pageX) / 50;
    let yAxis = (window.innerHeight / 4 - e.pageY) / 50;
    card.style.transform = `rotateY(${xAxis}deg) rotateX(${yAxis}deg)`;
  })
  //Movement in
  divs[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => {
    card.style.transition = "none";

    //Popout
    sneaker.style.transform = "translateZ(100px) rotateZ(-45deg)"
    title.style.transform = "translateZ(50px)"
    purchase.style.transform = "translateZ(25px)"
    info.style.transform = "translateZ(40px)"
  })

  //Movement Out
  divs[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", (e) => {
    card.style.transition = "all 0.5s ease"
    card.style.transform = `rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg)`

    //Popback
    title.style.transform = "translateZ(0px)"
    sneaker.style.transform = "translateZ(0px)"
    purchase.style.transform = "translateZ(0px)"
    info.style.transform = "translateZ(0px)"
  })
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.main {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 30%;
  margin: auto;
}

.container .card {
  min-height: 80vh;
  width: 70%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.container .card .sneaker {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 5rem 0;
}

.container .card .sneaker .circle {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  height: 12rem;
  width: 12rem;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(245, 70, 66, 0.75)), to(rgba(8, 83, 156, 0.75)));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(245, 70, 66, 0.75), rgba(8, 83, 156, 0.75));
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container .card .sneaker img {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 17rem;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
}

.container .card .info {
  width: 70%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
}

.container .card .info .title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
}

.container .card .info .text {
  font-size: .7rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #585858;
}

.container .sizes {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 2rem 0;
}

.container .sizes button {
  padding: .1rem 1rem;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container .sizes .active {
  color: white;
  background-color: #585858;
}

.container .purchase {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
}

.container .purchase button {
  border: none;
  background-color: #f54642;
  color: white;
  padding: .5rem 5rem;
  border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=styles.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="description" content="tenis hover 3D effect">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Adidas</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main" id="main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="sneaker">
          <div class="circle"></div>
          <img src="/adidas.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <h1 class="title">Adidas ZX</h1>
          <h3 class="text">future-ready trainver with wrapped boost for exception comfort</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="sizes">
          <button>39</button>
          <button>40</button>
          <button class="active">42</button>
          <button>44</button>
        </div>
        <div class="purchase">
          <button>Purchase</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="sneaker">
          <div class="circle"></div>
          <img src="/adidas.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <h1 class="title">Adidas ZX</h1>
          <h3 class="text">future-ready trainver with wrapped boost for exception comfort</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="sizes">
          <button>39</button>
          <button>40</button>
          <button class="active">42</button>
          <button>44</button>
        </div>
        <div class="purchase">
          <button>Purchase</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script defer src="/script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mirá esto al inicio de tu código. Con `querySelector()` estás seleccionando únicamente al primero que encuentra. ¿se ve que únicamente van a tomar al primero de la página?

```
//Movement
const card = document.querySelector(".card")
const main = document.querySelector(".main")

//Items
const sneaker = document.querySelector(".sneaker img")
const title = document.querySelector(".title")
const purchase = document.querySelector(".purchase")
const info = document.querySelector(".info")
```

Luego el evento se lo estás asignando muy correctamente a cada uno de los `.container`, que se disparan en el evento correcto pero hacen la animación sobre los elementos que seleccionaste mal.

En cambio, deberías seleccionar **el primer hijo** que encuentra para cada uno de los divs a los que les estás asignando eventos:

---

---

Quedaría así (fue lo único que corregí, hay más que estoy tentado de modificar, pero ya vas a ir encontrando temas para hacer preguntas):

```js
//For
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
let y = divs.length;

//Movement Animation
for (let i = 0; i < y; i++) {

  /* Corridos para adentro del bucle 
     VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV */
  
  let //Movement
      card = divs[i].querySelector(".card"),
      main = divs[i].querySelector(".main"),

      //Items
      sneaker = divs[i].querySelector(".sneaker img"),
      title = divs[i].querySelector(".title"),
      purchase = divs[i].querySelector(".purchase"),
      info = divs[i].querySelector(".info");
      
  /* AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA */

  divs[i].addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    let xAxis = (window.innerWidth / 4 - e.pageX) / 50;
    let yAxis = (window.innerHeight / 4 - e.pageY) / 50;
    card.style.transform = `rotateY(${xAxis}deg) rotateX(${yAxis}deg)`;
  })
  //Movement in
  divs[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => {
    card.style.transition = "none";

    //Popout
    sneaker.style.transform = "translateZ(100px) rotateZ(-45deg)";
    title.style.transform = "translateZ(50px)";
    purchase.style.transform = "translateZ(25px)";
    info.style.transform = "translateZ(40px)";
  })

  //Movement Out
  divs[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", (e) => {
    card.style.transition = "all 0.5s ease";
    card.style.transform = `rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg)`;

    //Popback
    title.style.transform = "translateZ(0px)";
    sneaker.style.transform = "translateZ(0px)";
    purchase.style.transform = "translateZ(0px)";
    info.style.transform = "translateZ(0px)";
  })
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.main {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 30%;
  margin: auto;
}

.container .card {
  min-height: 80vh;
  width: 70%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.container .card .sneaker {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 5rem 0;
}

.container .card .sneaker .circle {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  height: 12rem;
  width: 12rem;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(245, 70, 66, 0.75)), to(rgba(8, 83, 156, 0.75)));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(245, 70, 66, 0.75), rgba(8, 83, 156, 0.75));
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container .card .sneaker img {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 17rem;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
}

.container .card .info {
  width: 70%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
}

.container .card .info .title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
}

.container .card .info .text {
  font-size: .7rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #585858;
}

.container .sizes {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 2rem 0;
}

.container .sizes button {
  padding: .1rem 1rem;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container .sizes .active {
  color: white;
  background-color: #585858;
}

.container .purchase {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.75s ease-out;
}

.container .purchase button {
  border: none;
  background-color: #f54642;
  color: white;
  padding: .5rem 5rem;
  border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=styles.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="description" content="tenis hover 3D effect">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Adidas</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main" id="main">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="sneaker">
          <div class="circle"></div>
          <img src="/adidas.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <h1 class="title">Adidas ZX</h1>
          <h3 class="text">future-ready trainver with wrapped boost for exception comfort</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="sizes">
          <button>39</button>
          <button>40</button>
          <button class="active">42</button>
          <button>44</button>
        </div>
        <div class="purchase">
          <button>Purchase</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="sneaker">
          <div class="circle"></div>
          <img src="/adidas.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <h1 class="title">Adidas ZX</h1>
          <h3 class="text">future-ready trainver with wrapped boost for exception comfort</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="sizes">
          <button>39</button>
          <button>40</button>
          <button class="active">42</button>
          <button>44</button>
        </div>
        <div class="purchase">
          <button>Purchase</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script defer src="/script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema se solucionaría accediendo al elemento mediante la propiedad `currentTarget` del evento. Según la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) de mozilla, textualmente:

> Es interesante utilizar event.currentTarget cuando se asocia un mismo
> controlador de eventos a varios elementos.

Vamos con un ejemplo sencillo:

```js
// Obtiene todos los elementos con la clase test.
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.test');

// Recorre los elementos para asignar el evento 'mouseenter'.
items.forEach((item) => {

  item.addEventListener('mouseenter', (event) => {
  
    // Una vez ejecutado el evento, mediante la propiedad 'currentTarget' de 'event', accedemos al innerText del elemento.
    document.getElementById('txt').innerText = event.currentTarget.innerText;
  
  });

});
```

```css
.test {
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  border:solid 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

  <div class='test'>Div 1</div>
  <div class='test'>Div 2</div>
  
  <br />
  
  <div id='txt'>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```